# Different behavior of async with Visual Studio 2013(Windows8.1) and GCC 4.9(Ubuntu14.10)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11, gcc

async has different behavior(implementation) in Windows VS and Linux g++.

I tested it with the following code:

```
void Func1(){sleep(1000*1000);}
void Func2(){sleep(1000*2);throw runtime_error("An expected exception");}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  try{
    auto f1 = async(launch::async, Func1);
    auto f2 = async(launch::async, Func2);

    f2.get();//block here
    f1.get();
  }catch (exception& e){
    printf("exception: %s\n", e.what());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Func1 sleeps for a long time after launch.

Func2 is to throw an exception.

My observation is:

> In Windows, the exception is propagated immediately and the main thread(program) will catch it exit accordingly.
>
> In Linux, the exception is held on and the program doesn't exit until the sleep 1000 seconds in Func1 is over.

**So does anybody know in Linux, how to make the program catch the exception immediately and exit the program??**

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Linux compiler, but the fact that you say "doesn't exit until the sleep 1000 seconds in Func1 is over"  when your code has `sleep(1000 * 1000)` (just over 11 days) makes me think something else is going on.

Comment: In C++11 instead of just `sleep` use `std::this_thread::sleep_for`

Comment: Be aware that while on Windows `sleep` takes milliseconds as an argument, on linux it takes seconds. So waiting time of this code is expected to be 1000 times longer on linux.

Comment: that's why you should use standard `std::this_thread::sleep_for` - because just `sleep` is not standarized between platforms, and some take seconds, some take miliseconds

Comment: To avoid distraction, please think the snippet as pseudo. In my code, I used a function called mySleep which is an inline of sleep_for but I used sleep here for simplicity as it does not change the nature of the question I was asking. I also did not include header files. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `future`, obtained from `async`, has a blocking destructor. This "feature" is very controversial and has been discussed many times in the standard committee. See for example this SO question: [Why is the destructor of a future returned from `std::async` blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455104/why-is-the-destructor-of-a-future-returned-from-stdasync-blocking) The reasoning for such a behaviour is that there is no good portable way to terminate a thread.

Then `f2` throws an exception, the `f1`'s destructor is called, which waits until the tread (and thus `Func1`) finishes. Thus the `catch` block is executed only after the `Func1` finishes.

As of Windows behaviour, this is a known VC++ bug, as discussed here: [std::list<std::future> destructor does not block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698634/stdliststdfuture-destructor-does-not-block)

So, GCC on Linux is right, and VC++ on Windows is wrong here.

For a workaround, see for example [Workaround for blocking async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296284/workaround-for-blocking-async)

Answer (score -1):

Try comparing in `Func1` and `Func2` result of:

```
std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
```

`async` is not guaranteed by the standard to be executed in separate thread.

Probably you could use `std::packaged_task` with `std::thread`, like in the example:

```
std::packaged_task< int(int) > package{ Func2 };
std::future<void> f2 = package.get_future();
std::thread t { std::move(package) };

f2.get();       //block here until t finishes

t.join();
```

See my answer regarding `std::packaged_task` on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24164631/2622016

Comment: If the launch::async policy is explicitly specified, the task is actually guaranteed to be executed "as if in a new thread", making this answer wrong. See §30.6.8/3 (N3376). The thread ID may be the same as in a previous async() that has finished, but that doesn't prove anything because the standard only promises the ID of a new thread to be unique among *existing* threads in the first place, not threads that have previously existed (§30.3.2/1 in N3376).

Comment: right, and the real cause is the blocking `future` destructor just before catch block